# ES6 import/export not working with babel-jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

I have installed both babel and babel-jest for use within my project. I have configured my babel.config.js file as so:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

However I get the following error when trying to run my tests

```
import * as formObj from '../../../../public/Forms/Classes/Form.class.js';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

My package.json looks like this for babel, node, and babel-jest

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  },
  "engines": {
     "node": ">=11.0.0"
   }
```

Looking online- it seems like a lot of people who have issues with import/export in jest have issues due to their babel.config.js (or lack thereof). However- I made mine exactly how it is like in the jest docs. The error itself seems to step from a babel issue- but I'm failing to see where it could be.

I have tried various other things such as having a translation property in my jest config file, or trying different formats of importing my file, but nothing seems to work correctly.

Any advice greatly appreciated for solving this error.

Comment: try 
`npm install babel-preset-react`
`presets:['es2015','react']`

Comment: @Nymphetamine Same error :/